# Oracle : String to Datetime

Tags: sql, datetime

How can I convert this string date to datetime in oracle:

Tuesday, March 20, 2012

I tried   `to_char('Tuesday, March 20, 2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`   but it thrown `Invalid number error`.

Comment: Have you tried to read documentation for the function you use? Or you just used some random parameters and your assumptions and expected it to work?

Comment: Try [`to_date`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) instead of `to_char`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
TO_DATE('Tuesday, March 20, 2012', 'DAY, MONTH dd, yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

TO_DATE('Tuesday, March 20, 2012', 'day,month dd,yyyy')

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert to a datetime from a string, you should use the [to_date](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function. I think, but have not tested, the following format should work for you:

```
to_date('Tuesday, March 20, 2012', 'DAY, MONTH DD, YYYY'))
```